# How to change the color of a "svg" file that doesn't have the "fill" tag

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

I need to change the color of several "svg" files, but I'm having difficulties because they don't have the "fill" tag.

Heres is an example of one SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 95.95" style="enable-background:new 0 0 122.88 95.95" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M8.94,0h105c4.92,0,8.94,4.02,8.94,8.94l0,0c0,4.92-4.02,8.94-8.94,8.94h-105C4.02,17.88,0,13.86,0,8.94l0,0 C0,4.02,4.02,0,8.94,0L8.94,0z M8.94,78.07h105c4.92,0,8.94,4.02,8.94,8.94l0,0c0,4.92-4.02,8.94-8.94,8.94h-105 C4.02,95.95,0,91.93,0,87.01l0,0C0,82.09,4.02,78.07,8.94,78.07L8.94,78.07z M8.94,39.03h105c4.92,0,8.94,4.02,8.94,8.94l0,0 c0,4.92-4.02,8.94-8.94,8.94h-105C4.02,56.91,0,52.89,0,47.97l0,0C0,43.06,4.02,39.03,8.94,39.03L8.94,39.03z"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: add a fill atribute or a css fill

Comment: you can style it `style="color:red;"`

Comment: What is the context? your code is incomplete, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add it!

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 95.95"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 122.88 95.95" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill-rule: evenodd;
      clip-rule: evenodd;
      fill:red;
    }
  </style>
  <g>
    <path class="st0"
      d="M8.94,0h105c4.92,0,8.94,4.02,8.94,8.94l0,0c0,4.92-4.02,8.94-8.94,8.94h-105C4.02,17.88,0,13.86
      ,0,8.94l0,0 C0,4.02,4.02,0,8.94,0L8.94,0z M8.94,78.07h105c4.92,0,8.94,4.02,8.94,8.94l0,0c0,4.92-4.02
      ,8.94-8.94,8.94h-105 C4.02,95.95,0,91.93,0,87.01l0,0C0,82.09,4.02,78.07,8.94,78.07L8.94,78.07z M8.94
      ,39.03h105c4.92,0,8.94,4.02,8.94,8.94l0,0 c0,4.92-4.02,8.94-8.94,8.94h-105C4.02,56.91,0,52.89,0,47.97l0
      ,0C0,43.06,4.02,39.03,8.94,39.03L8.94,39.03z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```